# Upload any type of file to the server

Tags: javascript, php, html, nginx, web-development-server

How can I upload a file to the server without space limit?  I want to find out the code sequence in HTML and Javascript / PHP.  I only use NGINX.  Can there be a setting in NGINX that limits my upload (if so, how to disable it)?

Answer (score 1):

## `client_max_body_size`

NGINX has a setting that can limit the upload size of files. In your NGINX configuration, you can use `client_max_body_size` to set the max body size of incoming requests. Setting it to 0 disables it.

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 0;
}
```

There is more information available here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

Answer (score 0):

Disabling a web server upload limit is a bad idea - it would mean anyone can take your website down with a single line of code mimicking uploading a billion terabyte file. You can however adjust the upload size in your php.ini file under `upload_max_filesize`. You can also change the `client_max_body_size` entry in your nginx.conf.

Comment: Thanks!  This is good advice.  I just changed "client_max_body_size" to "nginx.conf".  But what is the source code in HTML and Javascript or PHP for upload?  I want something simple, but it works.